# Converting the values from array to ascii?

Tags: c++, c, embedded, hardware

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define msize 4096
struct memory
{
int a[msize];
};

void read(struct memory *m)
{
int i;
for(i=0;i<sizeof(msize);i++)
 {
    scanf("%d",&m->a[i]);
 }
}

int main()
{
struct memory m;
m.a[0]=250; // temperature value of 25,0
m.a[4]=01; // heater status OFF
m.a[8]=240; // temperature value of 24,0
m.a[12]=00; // heater status ON
m.a[16]=220; // temperature value of 22,0
m.a[20]=00; // heater status ON
read(&m);
return 0;
}
```

I have created a structure of a particular memory size and inserted some values to the array and reading those values from the array. I have a difficulty to convert this value to ASCII.

Comment: Have a look at itoa() method

Comment: What do you mean by 'convert to ASCII', do you mean you just want to print the values of the array?

Comment: @john I tried my bit then gave up.

Answer (score 1):

In `for(i=0;i<sizeof(msize);i++)`, it will not be `i<4096`,rather it will compare `i` to the size of an integer on your platform.In 32-bit systems,it will be `4`.So the loop will exit after just `4` iterations.

Further in your function, `&m->a[i]` will be `m->a[i]` as `m` is a pointer.

**PS** There is something very wrong with the logic of your program.You are assigning some values to the array elements in `main()`,but are overwriting the same in the function `read`().

As for converting integer values from an array to ASCII, it's fairly simple.You just have to use the `%c` format specifier and pass the array  elements are arguments.But I must point out there aren't 450 ASCII values to print.Since a character only has one byte,the max you can manage with it is 256 characters.

**PS** Many of the ASCII characters you want to print are not print-able.One is whose ASCII value equals `0`.

Comment: I understood but how to convert this read values from the array to ASCII ?

Comment: @user2306769 First use a `prinf()` that should prompt the user to enter the desired values.If you run the program,it will open and blink and the user will be clueless.

Comment: I dont want the user to enter any values but I am reading values through read function and converting this read values to ASCII .

Comment: @user2306769 If you don't want user to enter values, then why are you using `scanf()` in your `read()` function?`scanf()` will ask for  user input.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is inputting by character if you want to store in ASCII.

like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define msize 4096
struct memory {
    char a[msize];
};

/*
m.a[0]=250; // temperature value of 25,0
m.a[4]=01;  // heater status OFF
m.a[8]=240; // temperature value of 24,0
m.a[12]=00; // heater status ON
m.a[16]=220;// temperature value of 22,0
m.a[20]=00; // heater status ON
*/

int read(struct memory *m){
    char inputbuff[4+1];
    int i=0;

    memset(m->a, ' ', sizeof(m->a)/sizeof(m->a[0]));//initialize by space
    while(i<msize/(4+4)){
        printf("input temperature value e.g.25,0 : 250(and enter)\n");
        fgets(inputbuff, sizeof(inputbuff), stdin);
        strncpy(m->a + i*4, inputbuff, 3);
        //i+=1;
        printf("input heater status ON or OFF e.g.ON : 00 , OFF : 01(and enter)\n");
        fgets(inputbuff, sizeof(inputbuff), stdin);
        strncpy(m->a + (i+1)*4, inputbuff, 2);
        i += 1;
        printf("continue input? (y or n) : ");
        fgets(inputbuff, sizeof(inputbuff), stdin);
        if(*inputbuff=='n' || *inputbuff=='N'){
            break;
        }
    }
    return i;
}

int main(void){
    struct memory m;
    read(&m);
    {
        //check print
        m.a[msize-1]='\0';
        printf("%s\n", m.a);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**ADD for more**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define msize 4098

int *storeInt(void *address){
    int *ip =(int*)address;
    *ip = 777;//ip[0]=777;ip[1]=888;...
    return ip;
}

char *storeChars(void *address){
    char *cp =(char*)address;
    strcpy(cp, "hello");
    return cp;
}

void dump(void *address, size_t length){
    unsigned char *cp = (unsigned char*)address;
    size_t i;
    for(i=0;i<length;++i){
        if(i % 16 == 0) printf("\n");
        printf("%02X ", *cp++);
    }
}

int main(void){
    static char memory[msize];//create a static memory of a particular size
    char *block1, *block2;

    block1 = &memory[0];
    block2 = &memory[1024*2];//split a virtual

    int *ip;
    ip=storeInt(block1);//store some values in the memory
    printf("%d\n", *ip);//read the values from the memory

    char *cp;
    cp=storeChars(block2);//set hello\0
    printf("%s\n", cp);//say hello

    char ascValue[12];
    int value = *ip;//777
    //convert "value of int" to Ascii
    sprintf(ascValue, "%d", value);
    //Display it
    printf("value is %s\n", ascValue);

    dump(block1, 8);
    dump(block2, 8);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wanted to delete my answer as mine was the only one.Now that you too have answered,I'll let my answer stay.

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture I'm not sure what he will want to do. So those who had a lot of good answers.

Comment: My task is to read 1) create a static memory of a particular size (Is it possible to split the memory into blocks ??) 2) store some values in the memory 3) read the values from the memory 4) convert this values to Ascii 5) Display it in the terminal

Comment: @user2306769 You can create a static memory of a particular size (using array of a particular type).Each element will have same size and can be accessed by an array index.You can store values in that array as well.You can then read it and display it.But like I told you, there can be maximum 256 ASCII characters as long as a character has size of 1 byte.Even then,all ASCII characters can't be printed.Some are control characters.

Comment: please Could you give me a example ??

Comment: @user2306769 I added the sample.

Answer (score 0):

If your read() function is intended to read from memory and print to a terminal then you should be using printf() instead of scanf().  printf() will convert integer values to ASCII through the %d format string.  scanf() reads from the standard input and stores to memory.  scanf() converts from ASCII to integer through the %d format string.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
    #define msize 4096
    int a[msize];           
    void write()           
    {
     int i;
     for (i=0;i<msize;i++)
     {
      printf("value is %d", a[i]);  
     }
    }
    void main()
    {
    
     int *b1, *b2, *b3;             
     b1=&a[0];
     b2=&a[1024*2];         
     b3=&a[1024*3];
     b1[0]=250;                //inserting a value to the block  
     b1[4]=00;
     b2[1024]=240;
     b2[1028]=01;
     b3[2048]=260;
     b3[2052]=00;
    
    write();                     
    
    }